# What's the difference between "Behind you" and "with you"?

Tags: grammar, prepositional-phrases

I am behind you all the way.(Sense-In support of)

I am with you all the way. (Sense-In support of)

Are there any difference in meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is, or at least can be, a subtle difference of meaning, but in many situations the two phrases can be interchanged with no real change of meaning.

"*I am behind you*" suggests that the speak is in support of the listener, but the listener is the primary person involved, the one actually doing whatever the action is. "*I am  with you*" suggests, or at least may suggest, a more cooperative situation, a joint effort.  But this is a subtle difference, and in many cases a fluent speaker might use either of the two forms without considering this distinction

Answer (score 2):

The two expressions essentially mean the same thing.

> I am behind you

does imply that you are the leader and I am a supporter, but the implication is not strong. Moreover,

> I am with you

does not preclude the idea that you are the leader and I am a supporter.

In fact, I suspect most native listeners would not **consciously** be aware of the difference.